# Magento - Coupon code isn't case sensitive

Tags: magento

Is that normal that my coupon codes aren't case sensitive?
If I enter the code `test` or `TEST` or `TesT`, the result is the same..

Is it a miss configuration from my side or is it the normal way Magento does?

(magento 1.9.3.7)
Thank you

Comment: I think nobody wants case sensitive coupon codes? A case typo and you would like a customer to see an error message: Sorry dude, but the code is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coupon is not a password where you need the case. Coupon codes have to be unique and here it doesn't matter which case it is. So to prevent customer queries that implementation makes sense.